# How to deploy desktop application on an other computer?

Tags: c#, sql

I have Successfully published application not its working on an other computer .... but the thing is that when i try to insert some data in db at other computer its giving me an error of database instance ... now my point is how to setup and deploy a project (that is desktop base not web base) that should work on an other computer successfully .

Comment: You either need a networked DB, or you need to deploy the database/database engine with your application. How specifically you do this is very dependent on what database backend you are using, and what the goals of your application are, which you didn't share.

Comment: Show us the complete error. Are lot of reason for that to fail. Check string connection, maybe you are calling server `localhost` instead the remote location. Check the pc have persmision to access, Check Firewall, Check if DB have external access

Comment: I also have installed the SQL server 2008 on other Computer and same I am using . DB.mdf restored successfully on other computer . but when I insert some thing in other computer its giving me error related to database instance.

Comment: you don't want your databse to be reachable from outside normally, but in your case if you do: don't forget to port forward

Comment: I just want to deal with other computer. I don't to access it externally

Comment: @BaqirBajwa "An error related to database instance", that could be anything, and we need *exactly* what its telling you in order for us to help, we also need to see your connection string. If you are unwilling to provide that then I'd vote to close this question as it doesn't have the necessary information to diagnose or help resolve.

Comment: An SQL database credential can either be in SQL or Windows.  Use Windows Credential setup as a Group Account.  The local and remote computers need to be put into the same group so they can share user account passwords.  Then you should be able to connect to the database remotely.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="deployEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=deploy;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>